# Pycomm3 write_tag(tag,value) issue with Micro Logix 1400 PLC

Tags: python-3.x

code

```
from pycomm.ab_comm.slc import Driver as MLDriver 



ML = MLDriver()
while 1:
    try:
        if ML.open('192.168.2.150'):
            #print (ML.read_tag('F8:0',10))
            print (ML.write_tag('N7:0',10))
            ML.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        #continue
```

Error

> Error(can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str) packing the values to write  to the SLC write_tag(N7:0,10)

Read tag works fine but the write module is not working in pycomm3

Package Link :-

pip install git+https://github.com/bpaterni/pycomm.git@pycomm3

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug that should have been fixed recently